# how to use a fine tuned model in from langchain_community.llms.Ollama

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, ollama, gemma

How to use a fine-tuned model in Ollama `langchain_community.llms.ollama.Ollama`. The correct way of passing any model is passing in  `model : str` variable.

But the selection is only limited to https://ollama.com/library.

How can I add a fine-tuned gemma model as a string parameter.

I followed this video [Ollama - Loading Custom Models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BnnsQCmgLo)
, where he is able to add Quantized version of LLM into mac client of Ollama.

My use case is to fine tune a gemma:2b model, and save it to S3, and use this model in a compute instance as an API. My question revolves around how to intake this model in Ollama instance

- reading model from a path in compute instance
- Does the model require any quantization on top of it

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your custom model to HuggingFace, create a `Modelfile` (https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/modelfile.md), then build the model with `ollama`

Here's a reference > https://github.com/ollama/ollama